# Core Data Predicate Date Comparison

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, predicate

Im trying to fetch all the objects in an entity matching a user selectedDate (it's an NSDate).
The Core Data code is fine but my predicate keeps returning 0 results, the dates are the same in the database as the user is selecting.

How should the selectedDate be compared with a date from an entity using a predicate?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(eDate = %@)", selectedDate];
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your predicate looks to be fine.

The reason you're finding zero result are returned however may be that the dates aren't entirely the same.

For example:

`05/04/2012 13:37:00` will not match with `05/04/2012 13:37:01` as these two values are not exactly the same.

Do you want to check the date (day, month, year) as well as the time?

If you only want to check the date, you should create a start date and end date and compare them using the user selected date as a frame of reference.

Something similar to this should create a date and time for 00:00:00.

```
//gather current calendar
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

//gather date components from date
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

//set date components
[dateComponents setHour:0];
[dateComponents setMinute:0];
[dateComponents setSecond:0];

//return date relative from date
return [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```

Create another date by setting the hours, minutes and seconds to 23:59:59 and check that your user selected date falls between these ranges.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date BETWEEN %@", [NSArray arrayWithObjects:startOfDay, endOfDay, nil]]
```

Comment: It works, thanks. I was getting an error by using the array in the predicate but this worked..... @"eDate > %@ AND eDate < %@",date1, date2] Thanks again.

Comment: why do you add `NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit` in `components:fromDate:`just to toss it away?

Comment: My bad. This was code I pasted from a project that does actually use those components. I neglected to remove them for the purposes of this post. I'll amend that now ;] Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: the next 3 lines shouldnt be necessary too

Comment: I left the following lines in to illustrate to the OP how to set the time components for `23:59:59`. Feel free to down vote the answer if you feel it's not up to scratch ;]

Answer (score 12):

While in human communication date often is equal with day, it is not the same with NSDate objects: A NSDate represents a single moment in time. Dates that are different just in seconds aren't equal. And actually they dont represent days, month, year at all, as this is different from calendar system to calendar system

you must define for yourself if dates in the same minute, hour, day … are equal. So basically you must teach the program to allow some fuzziness.

here for minute resolution

```
NSDate *startDate = ....;
NSTimeInterval length;

[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSMinuteCalendarUnit 
                                startDate:&startDate
                                 interval:&length 
                                  forDate:startDate];

NSDate *endDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:length];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(eDate >= %@) AND (eDate < %@)", startDate, endDate];
```

For dates on the same day (aware of Timezones and Daylight Saving Times) you just would change this:

```
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit 
                                startDate:&startDate
                                 interval:&length 
                                  forDate:startDate];
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is much better than the accepted answer because it accounts for different calendars and does not hardcode the day's start and stop times.

Answer (score 2):

I can get working with some modifications to the accepted answer and using the iOS 8 API for create dates with time offset. The code:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[FFSharedCalendar singleton] getGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *startOfDay = [calendar dateBySettingHour:0 minute:0 second:0 ofDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
NSDate *endOfDay = [calendar dateBySettingHour:23 minute:59 second:59 ofDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"createdAt > %@ AND createdAt < %@", startOfDay, endOfDay];
NSArray* plans = [Plan MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate];
```

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I've recently spent some time attempting to solve this same problem and have resolved the following, now updated for iOS 8 and above...

```
NSDate *dateDay = nil;
NSDate *dateDayStart = nil;
NSDate *dateDayNext = nil;

dateDay = <<USER_INPUT>>;  //for example - selectedDate

dateDayStart = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] startOfDayForDate:dateDay];

//  dateDayNext EITHER
dateDayNext = [dateDayStart dateByAddingTimeInterval:(24 * 60 * 60)];

//  dateDayNext OR
NSDateComponents *dateComponentDay = nil;
dateComponentDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponentDay setDay:1];
dateDayNext = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComponentDay
                                                            toDate:dateDayStart
                                                           options:NSCalendarMatchNextTime];
```

...and the `NSPredicate` for the Core Data `NSFetchRequest` (as already shown above in other answers)...

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(dateAttribute >= %@) AND (dateAttribute < %@)", dateDayStart, dateDayNext]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I query in between 1 second above and below my actual Date. In my case its ok to add and subtract 1 second as I query for the restaurant orders so I know that it takes some time to punch a new order, for safe side I have 1 more orderNo field too.

```
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = Order.fetchRequest()
    let date_formatter = DateFormatter()
    date_formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"
    date_formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

    let createdDate = date_formatter.date(from: clientCreatedStr)

    let calendar = NSCalendar.current

    //as matching exact same datetime doesnt return anything
    let onesecondafter = calendar.date(byAdding: .second, value: 1, to: createdDate!)
    let onesecondbefore = calendar.date(byAdding: .second, value: -1, to: createdDate!)

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "offlineUniqueId == %@ AND (clientCreatedDate >= %@ AND clientCreatedDate <= %@)", offlineUniqueId, onesecondbefore! as NSDate, onesecondafter! as NSDate)

    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
```