# Date comparison in coredata NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, date, core-data, ios7, nspredicate

In my application I am using `CoreData`. Some date values are stored in coredata as `NSString`.
In my `Interface Builder` i have a textfield.When i enter a date on my textfield This date will compare dates in saved in coredata.

What will be the solution.I just goes through this way [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831600/core-data-predicate-date-comparison)  It Not be worked on my project because i want to convert string to date on my `NSPredicate` method.

My code is

```
NSPredicate *p3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"acc_date >= %@ AND acc_date<=%@", theDate, date1];
```

Here `acc_date` is dates from Database that is stored as string **theDate** and **date1** are my inputs

Comment: I want to compare the values with coredata

Comment: store 'acc_date' as 'NSDate' so that you can compare easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you continue to store the dates as strings then you cannot do any kind of comparison like you are attempting.

If you store them as actual `NSDate` instances then your comparison will work.  The issue is not with your predicate but with how you are storing your data in Core Data.

I would suggest migrating your database, either with a heavy migration or with a manual migration.  If your data is disposable then I would change the fields and reset your database to use `NSDate` instances.

Comment: I understand the problem.i just change the string to data format