# How to relate NSManagedObjects Dynamically based on their dates?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

Can you suggest how I can customize my `NSManagedObject`s so that a `Rep` entity can associate with a `Day` entity dynamically both when a Rep entity is created and when it's date property is changed?

I need help with the `NSPredicate` to search for `Day`s that have the same DD/MM/YYYY as the created `Rep` entity and I need to know which `NSManagedObject` methods to override when the `Rep` entity is created and when it's date property is changed.

I've attached a design flow chart to clarify.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Why? What is the purpose of the day entity? You have a date on the rep so why do you need the relationship?

Comment: @Wain Your comment makes sense…I did not think on it...

Comment: Days are going to coordinate between other entities that aren't shown. One challenge at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Here some suggestions to achieve what you want. For clarity I will divide my answer in two parts. The first regards the left part of your flow chart.

**Left part**

When you create a `Rep` you need to set up its date (*Note A*). For this I would override `awakeFromInsert` method. As per the documentation

> You typically use this method to initialize special default property
>   values. This method is invoked only once in the object's lifetime.

Once inserted the new object, you should run fetch request against `Day` with a specific predicate for searching for the same date.

Here you cannot simply use a predicate like

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(eDate = %@)", selectedDate];
```

It won't work. Instead use a solution described in [Core Data Predicate Date Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831600/core-data-predicate-date-comparison). The motivation is that an data 15/03/2014 16:02:00 will not match with 15/03/2014 16:02:01.

Based on the results returned from the fetch request you will grab the first object (*Note B*) in the array and set up the relationship. On the contrary you will create a new `Day` object and set up the relationship.

*Note A* This means you've created subclasses of `NSManagedObject` for `Rep` and Day
*Note B* How many `Day`s do you except to find?

**Right part**

For the second part I will rely on `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`. This notification is useful for listen for changes that occur.

When a changes occur the `notification` will contain `NSSet` for deleted, inserted or updated objects.

```
NSSet *updatedObjects = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];
NSSet *deletedObjects = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:NSDeletedObjectsKey];
NSSet *insertedObjects = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey];

// Place your logic here...
```

Obvioulsy you need to replace the comment with your logic there. It looks like the previous. But the important thing is to filter the objects that are returned in the notification. You are interested only for changes to `Rep`. So, for example

```
NSSet *objects = nil;
NSMutableSet *combinedSet = nil;
NSPredicate *predicate = nil;

NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];

objects = [userInfo valueForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey];
combinedSet = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:objects];

objects = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];
[combinedSet unionSet:objects];

objects = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:NSDeletedObjectsKey];
[combinedSet unionSet:objects];

predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entity.name == %@, 
              @"Rep"];
[combinedSet filterUsingPredicate:predicate];

if ([combinedSet count] == 0) {
    return;
}

// Place your logic here…
```

Finally, to maintain the consistency graph I would use a cascade relationships from `Rep` to `Day` and nullify to `Day` to `Rep`. This will allow you to remove `Day`s objects if are not attached to any `Rep`. Obviously it depends on your needs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Where should I put the code to observe to changes to the managed object context? For example I want to observe rep.date from Day...but day doesn't always exist in the managedObjectContext, sometimes it only exists as a fault.