# Compound predicate not returning the results

Tags: ios, sql, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nscompoundpredicate

I'm stuck with this problem for a while now I can't seem to think of a way to get it right. I'll try to explain it as clear as I can.

There are 3 entities in my core data model. **Workplace**, **Patient** and **Handover**.

[image]

A **Workplace** can have multiple **Patient**s. Also a **Patient** can belong to multiple **Workplace**s.

A **Patient** can have one **Handover** and vice versa.

In the app, a list of Workplaces are shown to the user. When the user selects a Workplace, I need to get a set Patients who belong to that selected Workplace and have Handovers for today. Since a Patient can have multiple Handovers, there can be duplicate records for Patients and that's okay.

This is what I'm doing now. First I retrieve the Workplace object for the user selected. Then I iterate through it's Patients and extract the IDs of Patient objects and collect them in to an array. Then I pass the array of patient IDs and the date to filter out the Patients who have Handovers for the given date.

```
let workplace = db.loadWorkplace(155) // 155 is the ID of the Workplace

var patientIDs: [Int] = []
for p in workplace.patients {
    let patient = p as Patient
    patientIDs.append(patient.id)
}
handovers = db.loadHandovers(patientIDs, date: NSDate.date())
```

This is the method that des the filtering.

```
public func loadHandovers(patients: [Int], date: NSDate) -> [AnyObject] {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Handover", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    let patientPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "patient.id IN %@", patients)
    let datePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "date > %@ AND date < %@", getStartDate(date), getEndDate(date))

    let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .AndPredicateType, subpredicates: [patientPredicate, datePredicate])

    fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
    fetchRequest.predicate = compoundPredicate

    var error: NSError?
    let result = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)
    return result!
}
```

The `getStartDate()` and `getEndDate()` methods convert the `NSDate` object and get its start time and end time to get a date frame. I have them used in some other places and they work. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832098/1077789) a detailed explanation about it.

Anyway my `loadHandovers()` method returns 0 results. It cannot be because when I insert data, I can see Handovers for today. Below is the SQL query that is executed from core data.

```
SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZDATE, t0.ZSIGNEDBY, t0.ZSTATUS, t0.ZPATIENT 
FROM ZHANDOVER t0 
JOIN ZPATIENT t1 ON t0.ZPATIENT = t1.Z_PK 
WHERE ( t1.ZID IN  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) 
AND ( t0.ZDATE > ? AND  t0.ZDATE < ?))
```

Can anyone please tell me if its something wrong with my predicates? Or if there are different ways to approach this altogether? I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: Many-to-Many relationships are considered bad design and you are hitting your problem because you are trying to work around this design flaw. Look into introducing a Bridge Entity between WorkPlace and Patient to turn your M-M relationship into two 1-to-M relationships. Then you can abandon the whole array workaround you have going and approach the original problem head on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the object graph, this seems really simple. Try to avoid the verbose fetch requests.

```
workplace.patients.filteredSetUsingPredicate(
  NSPredicate(format: "handovers.date > %@ && handovers.date < %@", 
              startOfDay, endOfDay))
```

You seem a bit confused about your own setup. If a patient only has one `Handover`, why call the relationship `handovers` in the plural?

Another flaw with your setup is illustrated by the contradictory statement

> "Since a Patient can have multiple Handovers..."

In your data model, a patient can have *one* handover, not many. The only explanation is that you are maintaining multiple `Patient` instances for the same patient, just because the patient has more than one handover. That is certainly illogical and a partial reason for your confusion and the error you encounter.

A better data structure, avoiding duplicate patients:

`Workplace <<---->> Patient <---->> Handover`

This assumes that the handovers have nothing to do with the hospital. If they do, you should use the `Handover` entity as a kind of join table as suggested by @DanK:

`Workplace <---->> Handover <<----> Patient`

If this is what you want, the application of the predicate would be even shorter:

```
workplace.handovers.filteredSetUsingPredicate(
  NSPredicate(format: "date > %@ && date < %@", startOfDay, endOfDay))
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about the object graph querying.